# Как отредактировать файл C:\Windows\...\hosts?

Tags: windows, c++, visual-studio

Если это вообще реально?

Преамбула (можно пропустить): *Здравствуйте, о Великие программеры, наконец-то наступило лето и, чтобы в очередной раз не терять это чудное время года в соц. сетях, в голову пришла идея "оградить" себя от таких зло-порталов как, например, вконтакте. Чтобы присечь всякий соблазн зайти на сайт, на всякий случай, отредактировал hosts сделав редирект vk.com и vkontakte.ru на 127.0.0.1. Дальше захотел "подарить" свободное время друзьям, т.е. написать простенькую программку, которая бы открывала и редактировала hosts, дописывая туда чудо-строки :)*

Возвращаюсь **к сути вопроса**: как организовать редактирование файла C:\Windows\system32\etc\hosts.*??? (расширение мне пока не понятно)* силами великого и могучего С++ (библиотека <fstream>)?

З.Ы. Пока что есть что-то типа такого:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        setlocale(NULL,"Russian");
    ifstream in("C:\\Windows\\system32\\etc\\hosts",ios::in);
    string str;
    while(in >> str)
    {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    system("pause >> void");
    return 0;
}
```

З.З.Ы. Пытался открыть как *.txt, но все безрезультатно

З.З.З.Ы. Спасибо, за неэкранированные бэкслешы, на ворнинги не обратил особого внимания

Comment: Язык тут непричём. У вас администраторские права есть? Если нету, вам нужно запросить elevation.

Comment: Я тебе открою тайну - hosts - он без расширения

Comment: если будет удобно %00

Comment: Ну, сейчас хоть работает?

ЗЫ: а для чего вы пытаетесь создать файл с именем `void`?

Comment: Просто этот файл (по крайней мере в Windows 7) лежит в другом месте.

     FILE *in = fopen("c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts", "rb");
     int c;
     while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
       fputc(c, stdout);

замечательно его читает.

(и вовсе не надо напрягаться с удвоением бэкслэшей).

Comment: @avp: тогда лучше `string(getenv("WINDIR")) + "/system32/drivers/etc/hosts"`

---
но всё же для _записи_ понадобится elevation

Comment: @VladD, наверное все, как Вы говорите, наверняка с getenv() правильней. 

Я вообще в винде не силен, работаю с правами админа, так что по большей части все открыто.

Comment: @avp: ЕМНИП, даже админу для записи понадобится elevation (метод предохранения от вирусов в условиях, когда поголовно все сидят под административной учёткой). Если у вас под руками есть винда, попробуйте добавить пустую строку в конец hosts и сохраниться, по идее, не должно получиться. (Если только у вас не переконфигурирован UAC.)

Comment: @VladD, у меня

     FILE *out = fopen(ETC, "ab");
     fputs("# xaxa\n", out);

исправно добавляет комментарии в конец `hosts`.

Comment: @avp: ваше админское кунг-фу сильнее моего :-)